# webpack output filename config error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

When I try to run npm run webpack, this shows "Error: 'output.filename' is required, either in config file or as --output-filename."

The config file is named correctly as webpack.config.js and is also in the root directory.

Below is the content in the config file:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports - {
    entry: './app.js',
    output: { path: __dirname, filename: 'bundle.js' },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /.jsx?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node-modules/,
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            }
        ]
    },
};
```

Would really appreciate help

Comment: "module.exports - {" --> `module.exports **=** {`

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error.
module.exports - 
should be:
 module.exports =
And btw, you do not need to require webpack in the configuration file.

Comment: Thanks! I'm also running into a problem where it's not outputting the bundle.js file. Should I create one?

Comment: You should not need to create bundle.js ahead of time. By root directory, do you mean OS root or your project root?